# boost::bind seems to produce different symbols with different compilers?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, callback, boost-bind

I have a shared object library which uses templates and callbacks.
I needed to port it to another system which uses an older version of g++ (4.1.2).

This is pseudo code of what I'm doing:

```
shrdPtr.reset( new DataRecvr<T>(aString,boost::bind(&MyClass<T>::myCallBack, this,_1)));
```

It works with the newer compiler however when I built it on the older system I had a symbol not found in runtime.

I used nm mySo.so | c++flt to compare the unworking so with ldd -u -r mySo.so

On the newer compiler (g++ 4.4.7) it produces :
    `DataRecvr<TemplateName>::DataRecvr(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<cahr> >const&, boost::function1,void,shrdPtr<TemplateName>&> const&`

while on the older compiler it produces:
`DataRecvr<TemplateName>::DataRecvr(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >const&, boost::function1,void,shrdPtr<TemplateName>& std::allocator<boost::function_base> >const&)`

As you can see, the older compiler produced extra stuff in the symbol which isn't getting resolved at runtime.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should have copy pasted the types instead of typing them over. Also, how did you establish the typenames?

Comment: The typenames are part of a system I'm building my shared object against.I just wrote 'TemplateName' as the actual type name is meaningless to the question ( I think ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was including an old version of boost.  The system that was giving me problems had multiple versions of boost on it.  When I set the include path to boost_144 my problem went away. Perhaps older versions of boost do weird things with bind that were incompatible withe constructor I was working with.